# TFS move a changset forward in the same branch

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We currently have up to 3 developers working in the same branch.

In Jan, I submitted changesets (say 100-110) that have since had some code overwritten by changsets (111-300) during merges from other team members.  I'm now just getting back to my project and I dread having to manually re-type all that code.

I can identify the exact changesets I need.

Is it possible to "merge" these specific changesets into the latest version of the same branch?

Comment: If your changes are all prior to faulty merges, get that specific (C110) version for your items - checkout - you should get conflicts resolve them this time with proper merge. If the merges done 111-300 are completly usless then you can rollback to your version.

Comment: @rene good looking out  :)... but you edited a question from 2013?

Comment: Yeah, there was a mishap: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399176/can-the-untagged-followers-please-attend-to-their-tag

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the changes in the same branch.
GO TO Branching and Merging option and click on the merging option you can merge the changes by choosing change set, date or label.
Hope you get my words